# Nested query in mongoose for checking existence of a value in another collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

in a `Node.js` app with `Mongoose`, i have two collections, `Users` and `Books`:

User schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_name: String,
    user_family: String,
    has_book: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

this is Book schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    book_name: String,
    book_user: String //contains id of a single user
});
```

I want to fetch all users and if each user has a book inside `Book` collection, then `has_book` field of that user filled with true. i think i need a nested query for this. one for fetching all users and one for checking existence of that book for each user. How i can write that nested query?

i write this:

```
User.find().sort("-_id").limit(5).exec(
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var userID = socket.request.session.passport.user;
        if(userID){
            //check for existence of a book belongs to each user
            // if exist, has_book field of User schema should be turn to true
        }
         return result //main result array after two queries
    }
);
```

i can't complete this code for second step of my need.

Comment: How did you used `return data` without `callback`, normally you can write nested query inside `User` query.

Comment: @greenlikeorange: i didn't understand, can you give me an example?

Comment: Ok, you commented "main result array after two queries" `return result`, mongoose's queries are in async, you may have to use these result in there with some callback. eg: `callback(result)` instance of `return result`

Comment: @greenlikeorange: thanks. but you have any idea about my main question?  a nested query that can check a value for each document from other collection? it's very confusing in Mongodb unlike relational databases. i need it but i can't find any way

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to save books ids on user schema.

But If you can't customize database do recessive function call

```
function checkForBook(users, callback, _results) {
  _results = _results || [];

  if(users.length < 1)
    callback(null, _results);

  var user = user.shift();
  Book.count({book_user: user._id}, function(err, bookCount){
    if(err)
      return callback(err);

    user.has_book = true;
    _results.push(user);

    checkForBook(users, callback, _results);
  });

}

User.find().exce(function(err, usersData){
  checkForBook(usersData, function(err, usersData){
    if(err)
      // do error handle
    else
      // do you favor 
  });
});
```